# Yandex map API как изменить картинку у ballon через json

Tags: javascript, json, yandex-maps-api, frontend

Ребят как у ballon изменить картинку 
именно через json

т.е вот допустим мой обьектом

```
{ 
"type": "Feature", 
"id": 48, 
"geometry": { 
"type": "Polygon", 
"coordinates": [55.723123, 37.406067] 
}, 
"properties": { 
"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><img src='https://i.goldvoice.club/0x0/http://storage7.static.itmages.r..' height='100'></b></font>", 
"balloonContentBody": "<b>Имя</b><span>Должность</span><p>Описание</p>", 
"hintContent": "<strong>Имя</s></strong>" 
} 
}
```

https://prnt.sc/m3fsj3 
Lightshot 
Screenshot

я про это 
есть такое решение 
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/?from=techmapsm..

но мне нужно именно что б с json

Помогите пожалуйста!!!

Comment: Подозреваю что вы спрашиваете не про балун, а про внешний вид метки? Чтобы метка выглядела вот так https://jsfiddle.net/Lqy6ps45/ ?

Comment: Спасибо большое!